# Error The request failed with HTTP status 503 Service Unavailable only for particular report

Tags: asp.net, iis, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm occurring this weird error when opening Reporting Service from My ReportViewer component in my ASP.net web application in the server,
**The request failed with HTTP status 503 Service Unavailable.**
The weird things are:
- I can open all reports in the ReportServer including the report which has that error.
- I can open other reports besides the report which has that error from My ReporViewer component in the server.
- I can open the report which has that error on my local computer.

I've tried to restart all the services, but the error still persists.
Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: 503 means your application pool has been stopped because of an unhandled crash exception. Have you checked what error message is logged in application event or system event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the report and re-create it makes no error. It's very strange because the error said service unavailable.